# Isomorphism between polynomial ring and ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\psi:R[X_1,..,X_d] \rightarrow S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism from polynomial ring $R[X_1,..,X_d]$ to ring $S$ with $\operatorname{Ker}(\psi)=I=I_0R[X_1,..,X_d]$, where $I_0$ is an ideal of $R$. Show that (1) $I_0=\operatorname{Ker}(\psi|_R)$ and (2) $S\cong\psi(R)[X_1,..,X_d]$.

For the first question: From $I_0R[X_1,..,X_d] = \{i_0f:i_0 \in I_0,f \in R[X_1,..,X_d]\} $ follows that $\forall f \in R[X_1,..,X_d]: \psi(f) \neq 0$ we have $\psi(i_0f) = \psi(i_0)\psi(f) = 0$, hence $\psi(i_0) = 0, \forall i_0 \in I_0$. It proves that $I_0 \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}(\psi|_R)$. Also $\forall r \in \operatorname{Ker}(\psi|_R): \psi(r)=0$,  so  $\operatorname{Ker}(\psi|_R) \subseteq I_0$, hence $\operatorname{Ker}(\psi|_R) = I_0$.

For the second question: isomorphism theorem states that $R[X_1,..,X_d]/I \cong S$, so maybe prove $R[X_1,..,X_d]/I \cong \psi(R)[X_1,..,X_d] $?

Comment: What have you tried? MSE is not designed to do your HW for you!

Comment: @bounceback check edits

Comment: 1) $R \to \psi(R)$ is necessarily surjective, and if $k \in \text{ker}(\psi\vert_R)$ then $k \subset I$, but $k \subset R$ so the only possibility is that $k \subset I_0$. For the other direction, use that $I_0 \subset I$.

2) Convince yourself of why $$S \cong \psi(R)[X_1,\dots,X_d] \cong R/I_O[X_1,\dots,X_d] \cong R[X_0,\dots,X_d]/<I_0>$$

Comment: @bounceback Thanks, the first one is done. As for the second, I was able to convince myself only of the second isomorphie.

Comment: Rather than a for all $f$ with the colon meant to signify "such that", I would instead say "if there is an $f$ such that". However, your argument does not hold, because the fact that a product is equal to $0$ does not mean that one of the factors is equal to $0$. You do not know that $S$ does not have zero divisors. So your conclusion that $\psi(i_0)=0$ does not follow.

Comment: (That is, you don't conclude $\psi(i_0)=0$ because $\psi(i_0)\psi(f)=0$ but $\psi(f)\neq 0$; you conclude it because $I_0\subseteq I=\mathrm{ker}(\psi)$ (which is what you were trying to argue anyway., though it is a given)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes it's true. I'm trying to adopt argument from bounceback above.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It seems tricky that $I_0 \subseteq I$ considering that they are ideals from different rings.

Comment: @AromaTheLoop By *definition*, $I=I_0R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$. In particular, if $i_0\in I_0$, then $i_0 = i_01 \in I_0R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]=I$; I'm assuming your rings have an identity, of course.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, they are assumed with identity. What bugs me is that $i_01_{R[X_1,..X_d]} \neq i_01_R$ and $1_R\notin I$

Comment: @AromaTheLoop: You do understand that $R$ is a subring of $R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$, right? The unit of $R$ is also the unit of the polynomial ring. Just like the $1$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the one in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$. I mean, you don't seem disturbed by "$I_0R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$", so surely you understand that elements of $R$ are viewed as elements of $R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ as well.

Comment: @AromaTheLoop: Also, **by definition**, for any $a$ in $R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$, $a1_{R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]} = a$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am quiet disturbed by $I_0R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ actually, your argument seem to lower that disturbance to some degree though so thanks

Comment: @AromaTheLoop: However you defined the polynomial ring, you must have proven that it contains an isomorphic copy of $R$ via a canonical embedding $i\colon R\hookrightarrow R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ that is a unital map of rings with identity (that is, it sends $1_R$ to $1_{R[x_1,\ldots,x_d]}$. We then identify $R$ with its image inside of the polynomial ring and simply consider $R$ as being contained as a subring of the polynomial ring.